# Is it possible for a class to define a result for the %d format specifier?

Tags: python, string, class, formatting

I have an instance of a class `A` passed as the value to the format specifier `%d` in the string formatting using the `%` operator.  Without any preparation, this will result in the following error message: `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not A`:

```
class A: pass

'%d' % A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not A
```

If the class `A` defines a method called `__int__`, this gets called:

```
class A:
  def __int__(self):  return 42

'%d' % A()
'42'
```

In my use case I would like the formatting with `%d` create a string representations for the instances of my class which do not look like a number (but instead an arbitrary string like `n/a`, `²³`, or similar).

Is this possible?

I was considering returning another special object in the `__int__` method but that resulted in a warning (only returning basic ints is allowed, anything else might become illegal in later versions; I'm trying on Python 3.7.4, btw) and no success eventually.

I know it is an easy task using the `__format__` method in combination with the `'{0}'.format(a)` way of formatting strings, but that's not what I'm asking for.  I'm specifically and only asking about formatting using the `%d` specifier in formatting string used with the `%` operator.

Comment: No, this is not provided. `%d` *explicitly* means "convert the value to integer, then interpolate the integer value into the string"; and this logic is implemented within the `%` operator itself. This kind of inflexibility is one of the many reasons not to use this ancient formatting technique :)

Comment: You're asking how to code a contradiction in the language definition.  This is very much like asking how you can make variables of type integer hold string values.  That's not what it's designed to do, and is a violation of its basic existence.

Comment: @Prune I see no reason why this should contradict anything.  It could simply be that in case `%d` is applied to a user-defined object, a special method of this object is asked to do the job (e.g. `__percent_format__(specifier)`).  That way is used with the more modern `.format()` and I see no reason why it shouldn't be done with the older `%` operator formatting.  In fact, it could even be added today.  It still would not contradict anything.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a string using the %d operator will not work. As far as I know there is no built in function to change this. However, if you want to print a string representation of an object their are three different ways using the modulo operator (%).

1. %s - Returns a string using the str() built in method
2. %r - Returns a string using the repr() built in method
3. %a - Returns a string using the ascii() built in method

Using these three you can customize the string using their corresponding dunber methods. For example, if you were to use %s it would use the built str() method. In order to edit what the str() method returns you would put this within your class definition.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "String Representation"
```

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) describes why %d can't print strings perfectly. Make sure to scroll down to where the % explanation is (about half way down the page.)

Comment: In my case, a library (i.e. not my code and not subject to change) is using `%d` for formatting the input I provide, and I am wondering if I could sneak in the special value n/a for not available.  This works for all computations the library does with the provided values (because the class I wrote for n/a has `__mul__` and `__add__` methods etc. (which all return an n/a object again).  Only the percent-formatting still is a problem.